# How to exclude a pattern between a pair of parentheses?

Tags: regular-expression, filetype-python

I have the following Python code

```
z=xyz%10
gvu.set_ticks(ax, xticks=[45, 50],
              yticks=[-25, -20, -15])
```

After this substitution, in visual mode

```
:s/\([^=]\)\ *\(=\)\ *\([^=]\)/\1 \2 \3/g
```

the code becomes

```
z = xyz%10
gvu.set_ticks(ax, xticks = [45, 50],
              yticks = [-25, -20, -15])
```

But I don't want the substitution to apply to the equal signs inside parentheses.
What I want is

```
z = xyz%10
gvu.set_ticks(ax, xticks=[45, 50],
              yticks=[-25, -20, -15])
```

Comment: Try this: `sil *s/\n/\="\x01"/ | sil s/\%(^\%(([^()]*)\|[^()]\)*\)\@<==/ = /g | sil s/\%x01/\r/g`.

Comment: As a general piece of advice, to format Python code (or that of most other languages) I'd recommend using an external formatting tool primarily, such as `black`, `pyformat` or `yapf` (in Python's case.) It will take care of all style recommendations (not just that one) and it's easy to integrate it into Vim.

Comment: @filbranden Thanks for introducing me to these formatting tools. I am using yapf now, it is very convenient. I still want to have a vim solution (the one that is proposed above does not work, and add  extra spaces when not necessary). I have a similar vim-regex problem in Latex but for excluding a pattern between begin and end environment instead of parentheses.

Comment: @user938271 The first `*` should be a `%`. This looks pretty interesting, joining all lines so you can match it in a single line. You should consider posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to visually select the lines on which you want to perform the substitution, then run this:

```
sil *s/\n/\="\x01"/ | sil s/\%(^\%(([^()]*)\|[^()]\)*\)\@<==/ = /g | sil s/\%x01/\r/g
```

If you want to operate on all the lines in the buffer, replace the range `*` with `%`.

---

Broken down:

```
" join all lines in the visual selection into a single one
sil *s/\n/\="\x01"/

" add spaces around equal signs outside parentheses
sil s/\%(^\%(([^()]*)\|[^()]\)*\)\@<==/ = /g

" split back the lines
sil s/\%x01/\r/g
```

Comment: I only get it to work in normal mode, with * or %. I changed it slightly to exclude == and not to add extra space, `sil *s/\n/\="\x01"/ | sil s/\%(^\%(([^()]*)\|[^()]\)*\)\@<=\([^=]\)\s*=\s*\([^=]\)/\1 = \3/g | sil s/\%x01/\r/g`

Answer (score 1):

I came up with:

```
g/^[^(]*=[^)]*$/s/[^ ]\zs=\ze[^ ]/\ =\ /g
```

The global search for a `=` that has no `(` before and no `)` after.

The substitute command changes each `=` not surrounded by spaces with a `_=_` (with spaces). `zs` and `ze` (start and end) are delimiters: only the `=` will be replaced here, not the whole pattern.

There must be numbers of edge cases I did not check.